# Removing and appending elements in a FIXML message

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Very new to Python.  We're developing a test tool to generate test FIXML messages from component data captured in XML format.  We have to use ElementTree / Python 2.7.

The principal is to load a basic template of a message (in this case the msg contains non-business header info etc.) and enrich it by replacing certain whole elements with the the sub elements/attributes but with specific business content (such as product details, party details etc.) so we can produce variations of trades using a handful of templates.

An example of the XML is as follows:

```
<TrdMtchRpt TrdID="$+" RptTyp="0" TrdDt="$date" MtchTyp="4" LastMkt="ABCD" LastPx="123.45">
 <Hdr SID="GTS" TID="Somewhere" Snt="$timestamp" />
 <ApplSeqCtrl ApplID="D" ApplSeqNum="$appseqnum" />
 <InstrmtMtchSide>
  <Instrmt Sym="" MMY="" />
  <Stats Typ="" Px="" Tm="" Sz="" />
  <TrdMtchSide TrdID="" Side="" SideQty="">
   <TrdRptOrdDetl OrdID="" ClOrdID="" ClOrdID2="">
    <OrdQty Qty="" />
   </TrdRptOrdDetl>
  </TrdMtchSide>
 </InstrmtMtchSide>
</TrdMtchRpt>
```

The intention in this case is to parse the base file using etree then replace the "InstrmtMtchSide" element with that from another.

Can someone please give me some guidance on how this can be performed using ElementTree?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a document as a template and update some elements depending on the message to be delivered, I'd advice to use a templating system.

For example with [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) could be used as follows:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template_str = """
<TrdMtchRpt TrdID="$+" RptTyp="0" TrdDt="$date" MtchTyp="4" LastMkt="ABCD" LastPx="123.45">
 <Hdr SID="GTS" TID="Somewhere" Snt="$timestamp" />
 <ApplSeqCtrl ApplID="D" ApplSeqNum="$appseqnum" />
 <InstrmtMtchSide>
  <Instrmt Sym="{{ sym }}" MMY="{{ mmy }}" />
 </InstrmtMtchSide>
</TrdMtchRpt>
"""

template = Template(template_str)
print template.render(sym='aaa', mmy='bbb')
```

Example output:

```
<TrdMtchRpt TrdID="$+" RptTyp="0" TrdDt="$date" MtchTyp="4" LastMkt="ABCD" LastPx="123.45">
 <Hdr SID="GTS" TID="Somewhere" Snt="$timestamp" />
 <ApplSeqCtrl ApplID="D" ApplSeqNum="$appseqnum" />
 <InstrmtMtchSide>
  <Instrmt Sym="aaa" MMY="bbb" />
 </InstrmtMtchSide>
</TrdMtchRpt>
```

Note: There are many other template systems like [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), [django-template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/) or [genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/).

Edit: If you really want to programmatically generate the new xml document, the following code is an example the replaces the `InstrmtMtchSide` with a `NewElement` one:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse(xml_filename)
root = tree.getroot()
element = root.find('InstrmtMtchSide')
root.remove(element)
etree.SubElement(root, 'NewElement')
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Example output:

```
<TrdMtchRpt LastMkt="ABCD" LastPx="123.45" MtchTyp="4" RptTyp="0" TrdDt="$date" TrdID="$+">
 <Hdr SID="GTS" Snt="$timestamp" TID="Somewhere" />
 <ApplSeqCtrl ApplID="D" ApplSeqNum="$appseqnum" />
 <NewElement /></TrdMtchRpt>
```

Comment: Hi @jcollado, Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately the decision has been made to use this multi template & specific element replacement approach with no hard coding as we have a large amount of message types to account for.  I'll take a look at your recommendations for template systems nonetheless.  Thanks and regards, Nick H.